# Matlab Solve function solutions don't satisfy equation

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I have an equation that theoretically has to only have one positive solution and the rest must be negative. So I used matlab solve function but two of the solutions are positive instead of one. Then as expected, by testing the solutions one of them does not satisfy the equation which means it is not the proper results. Here is the code:

```matlab
n=4
c = 10.3343;
theta = [51.7924 ; 4.3564 ; 0.0103 ; 1.3505];
syms x
eqn = sum(sqrt(x.^2 + theta))  - n.*x == c;
sol = solve(eqn,x);
% find pi
xdouble = double(sol);
xdouble(xdouble<0) = [];

cnew1  = sum(sqrt(xdouble(1).^2 + theta)) - n.*xdouble(1)
cnew2  = sum(sqrt(xdouble(2).^2 + theta)) - n.*xdouble(2)
```

The results are

```
cnew1 =

   10.5373


cnew2 =

   10.3343
```

which clearly second one is the proper answer, but I am confused why matlab generates the first incorrect solution? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could happens that `solve` produce spurious solutions (a.k.a incorrect solutions). Check the wikipedia article about [spurious solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions).

Why ?

Because `solve` try to solve your problem analytically. During this process matlab can transform your initial equation to something easier to solve.

For example if we have the following equation:

```
x+1=0
```

It is obvious that the solution is `x = -1`.

But matlab could do something like:

```
x   = -1
x^2 = (-1)^2 
x^2 = 1
```

And now we have two solutions: -1 and 1. 1 is a spurious solution.

So you have 2 choices to avoid this problem:

1. Check that the solutions returned by `solve` are correct.
2. Solve the equation with `vpasolve`, `vpasolve` use **numerical** analysis. So, strictly speaking,`vpasolve` do not solve your equation but instead determine by iteration the possible solutions.

So:

```
sol = vpasolve(eqn,x);
```

will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

**1.- MATLAB does not use `sum()` in this context**

In the context of this question MATLAB disregards the `sum()`  operator around `sqrt` because for `sum` to be used it must be on a known and finite array of values.

Since an equation is to be solved with `solve`, and no actual range is defined, because it's command `solve` the one to find roots, if any root to be found, `sum` cannot operate without the range defined by a concise array of discrete elements to be summed.

And there's no sampling step either, because for command `solve` to be accurate solve it has to dive down enough decimals therefore an array step is not specified when defining equations for `solve`.

So command `sum` ignored, and in fact one can remove it from the equations to solve.

```
n=4
c = 10.3343;
th = [51.7924 ; 4.3564 ; 0.0103 ; 1.3505];

figure
ax=gca
hold on

for k=1:1:numel(th)
    f1=@(x)  sum(sqrt(x.^2 + th(k)))  - n.*x - c;
    fplot(ax,f1,[-10 10])
end

plot(ax,[-10 10],[0 0],'Color','k')
grid on
```

[image]

```
for k=1:1:numel(th)
    f1=@(x)  (sqrt(x.^2 + th(k)))  - n.*x - c;
    fplot(ax,f1,[-10 10])
end
```

[image]

With or without `sum` the obtained roots are identical :

```
syms x

xr1=[];

for k=1:1:numel(th)
    
    eqn = sum(sqrt(x.^2 + th(k)))  - n.*x == c;
    
    sol = solve(eqn,x);
    % find pi
    xd = double(sol);
    xr1=[xr1;xd];
    
end

xr1
```

roots with `sum` in the equations

```
xr =
  -0.774025412748041
  -1.881122895419566
  -2.066361839624184
  -2.004354732448066
```

And without

```
xr1=[];

for k=1:1:numel(th)
    
    eqn =(sqrt(x.^2 + th(k)))  - n.*x == c;

    sol = solve(eqn,x);
    xd = double(sol);
    xr1=[xr1;xd];

end

xr1

xr =
  -0.774025412748041
  -1.881122895419566
  -2.066361839624184
  -2.004354732448066
```

Observe that both the shape of the graphs are the same, and the roots are also exactly the same, with or without `sum` around `sqrt`

**2.- There are 4 equations, not one**

Yes one may call an array of equations thrown at solve as just *'an equation'* or a *'a vector equation'*.

But because the question starts with *'I have an equation'* it's worth pointing out that actually there are 4 curves because there are 4 values of `theta`, I use `th`, therefore 4 functions, 4 equations, not one, have been defined.

**3.- `sqrt` may have 2 roots**

Ok when the parabola only touches the x axis on one point there's only 1 real root, and when the parabola is all above the x axis there are not real roots.

BUT when there are real roots, most likely, they come in pairs.

As poised the equations `eqn` you are implicitly asking for ANY value satisfying `sqrt` and that implies that `-sqrt` should also be considered

```
for k=1:1:numel(th)
    f1=@(x)  -(sqrt(x.^2 + th(k)))  - n.*x - c;
    fplot(ax,f1,[-10 10])
end

xr2=[];

for k=1:1:numel(th)
    
    eqn = -(sqrt(x.^2 + th(k)))  - n.*x == c;
    
    sol = solve(eqn,x);
    % find pi
    xd = double(sol);
    xr2=[xr2;xd];
    
end

xr2

xr =
  -4.737601253918626
  -3.630503771247101
  -3.445264827042483
  -3.507271934218601
```

**4.- 2nd part of the equations to solve**

It seems the `cnew` expression is also part of the equations, I use `cn1` `cn2`.

Now the resulting `cn1` matches the only expected result of `10.3343`

```
cn1=[];
for k=1:1:numel(th)
    cn1  =[cn1 ; (sqrt(xr1(k).^2 + th(k))) - n.*xr1(k)];
end
cn1

cn1 =
  10.334300000000001
  10.334300000000001
  10.334300000000001
  10.334300000000001



cn2=[];
for k=1:1:numel(th)
    cn2  =[cn2 ; (sqrt(xr2(k).^2 + th(k))) - n.*xr2(k)];
end
cn2

cn2 =
  27.566510031349011
  18.709730169976805
  17.227818616339867
  17.723875473748812
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation but you are actually solving another problem...
```
for k=1:1:numel(th)
    f1=@(x)  (sqrt(x.^2 + th(k)))  - n.*x - c;
    fplot(ax,f1,[-10 10])
end
```
is a system of equations with one square root in each. mine is a summation of square root of terms including different theta values. Also the assumption that matlab cannot use sum on the variable expression of x is also incorrect. I have printed eqn when using sum and separately when adding up 4 terms and the eqn is exactly the same.

Comment: Hi Hafez, then with sum(sqrt(x.^2 + theta)) you mean sqrt(x.^2 + theta(1))+sqrt(x.^2 + theta(2))+sqrt(x.^2 + theta(3))+sqrt(x.^2 + theta(4)) ? if so, even then, the solution cn1 still applies, the same 10.3343 root for all cases because only then the sum()=0. There are no roots cancelling each other.